# Solve: $y'=(4x+y+1)^2$, with $y(0)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have not come across this kind of differential eqn in past. I have no idea how to start it. I guess just a hint will be enough.

Comment: Just a suggestion : try $z=4x+y+1$

Comment: Yeah thanks. just figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

I got it. Take $4x+y+1=z$ and then differentiate with respect to $x$ and substitute in the given differential eqn.